# how to get my javascript output in json format

Tags: javascript, function, node-red

image is the javascript code for the function node

I want same output as shown just value data to be in columns rather than in rows

Comment: Hello, sorry, your question is very unclear, could you try improving the formatting but also make it more understandable what you want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+to+JSON+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It is still completely unclear what you mean. When do you want what to be in columns?

Comment: the values that i have highlighted.

Comment: u can see the output i m getting. there is value: "{"Relay Abc":"Off","Relay Bedf":"On","MP  R31":0,"NM  R2":-1,"SP  R3":-1,"Current":0,"Voltage":0,"Voltage2":51}"        THIS THING I WANT IN COLUMN

Comment: When? In the console?

Comment: YES IN MY NODRED DEBUG CONSOLE........I HAVE MENTION THE CODE IMAGE

Comment: success: true
datatype: "string"
timestamp: 09140820
registerId:123"
value: "{"Relay Abc":"Off","Relay Bedf":"On","MP  R31":0,"NM  R2":-1,"SP  R3":-1,"Current":0,"Voltage":0,"Voltage2":51}"
deviceID: "5A6B3038-8FA0-43F8-A54B-BCE52902337C"
tagName: "k_Test_02"
deviceName: "abc_SERVER"          THIS IS THE OUPUT, HERE ONLYT CHANGE I WANT IS THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE SAME ONLY VALUE SHOULD COME IN COULMN WISE RATHER THAN ALL IN ONE ROW

Comment: Right now it is an invalid string. Please show the original code that produces it and stop posting code in comments

Comment: The code in the function node currently doesn't actually do anything meaningful.

Comment: THE image is the original code use in nodered: function node

Comment: Please do not post images of code, you should always post the actual text and format it as code. Images are hard to read, unsearchable and impossible for people that use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work I think.

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

Comment: i m not from coding background, can u explain where  to add

Comment: If you can get output, it is greate, and now you can put your output into JSON.parse()

JSON.parse(output)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content of the input `msg.payload.value`

Then you should remove the function node and replace it with a change node that will.

`move` `msg.payload.value` to `msg.payload`

[image]